# По этимологии слова "ромашка"

Tags: этимология

А откуда в русском языке взялось слово "ромашка"? Оно как-то связано со словом "роман"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Связано. Происходит от лат. anthemis rōmāna, chamaemēlum rōmānum. Отсюда русск. диал. роме́н, раме́н, южн. (Даль), укр. рома́н, белор. рамо́н, ро́мон, сербохорв. ра̀ман, ра̏менак (род. п. ра̏ме̑нка), также раме́нак (род. п. -е́нка), словенск. rmȃn, rоmа̑n "тысячелистник, Achillea millefolium", чешск. rmen "римская ромашка", словацк. rumanček — то же, польск. roman, rоmаnеk "молочай", rumian "римская ромашка". Вост.-слав. слова заимств. явно через польск. посредство, вряд ли через франц. camomille romaine.Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу причин связывать ромашку с *романом* в каком-либо значении. Мало того, что пришли в русский язык эти слова разными путями (обычно этого достаточно, чтобы отказать в общей этимологии в языке-мишени, русском в нашем случае, так ещё тот *роман*, от которого ромашка произошла, означает не новеллу или адюльтер, а всего лишь "романский" или "римский".